# How to get posts from Facebook with speicific hashtag wihtout user login in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi In my iOS application i need to list the facebook public posts with specific hashtag.
How to get it wihtout user logged in with facebook.

Please help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: public post search is deprecated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Graph API v2.0, the search for public posts has been deprecated. hence, it's no longer possible to search for hashtags.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api

> Public Post search is no longer available. (`/search?type=post&q=foobar`)